# To Embed Wmp Video in jsp and run Using tomcat server

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, video

I am using Eclipse and tomcat to build my project in which i have to make a website which contains training videos. I am using WMP for playing the video and embedding it in jsp. Also we will be using tomcat on my machine as a server. Now when i play the application in my pc it works fine on chrome and IE. But when i have to run it on other pcs (all connected by LAN)the video doesn't play. I think the issue is with where should the video file be put within my pc so that all machines within the LAN can view the video. This is my code. Right now the url for my video is the **"src"** folder of my project. The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 .center {
  margin: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
</style>


<body>
<p>hello!!</p>
<div class = "center">
<OBJECT id=WindowsMediaPlayer1 width=320 height=264 hspace=5 
        vspace=5 classid=clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6 border="5"     align="middle">
          <param name="URL" value="C:\Users\T00244\workspace\draft1\src\selenium.mp4"  > ------>>>> // the location of the video file in my pc right now!!
          <param name="rate" value="1">
          <param name="balance" value="0">
          <param name="currentPosition" value="0">
          <param name="defaultFrame" value>
          <param name="playCount" value="1">
          <param name="AutoStart" value="false">
          <param name="currentMarker" value="0">
          <param name="invokeURLs" value="-1">
          <param name="baseURL" value>
          <param name="volume" value="50">
          <param name="mute" value="0">
          <param name="uiMode" value="full">
          <param name="stretchToFit" value="-1">
          <param name="windowlessVideo" value="0">
          <param name="enabled" value="-1">
          <param name="enableContextMenu" value="-1">
          <param name="fullScreen" value="0">
          <param name="SAMIStyle" value>
          <param name="SAMILang" value>
          <param name="SAMIFilename" value>
          <param name="captioningID" value>
          <param name="enableErrorDialogs" value="0">
          <param name="_cx" value="9260">
          <param name="_cy" value="9790">
<EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2'
    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'
    id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' 
    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' 
    showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="320" height="264"
    src="selenium.mp4" autostart="false" designtimesp='5311'>
  </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now according to me the issue is with where the video file must be put within the pc so that it can be broadcast on other pcs in LAN. So what should be the path name alteration. As in where should I put the video file.

Also if you think something else could be the problem. Then please notify and suggest solution.

Ps: Please try and help!!! Desperate Situation.